# Python conditional statements in f-string with format specifiers

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

In this code snippet:

```
b = False
print(f'{a if b else ""}')
```

I would like to use format specifier for `a`, e.g. `a:.2f`. None of these work with Python 3.10:

```
print(f'{a:.2f if b else ""}')
print(f'{(a:.2f) if b else ""}')
print(f'{{a:.2f} if b else ""}')
```

What is the solution?

---

I would like to keep the conditional inside f-string, since there will be a few of them in different places in a multiline string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the condition inside the `f-string` if you use two of them, the 2nd one for the `a:.2f`

```
print(f'{f"{a:.2f}" if b else ""}')
```